# "export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Tags: angular

I have a project @Next angular, After `npm install`, when we have to run `ng serve` the project then we are facing the below error.  I just can't figure out why this is happening. Can you please help and resolve the issue.

I even tried updating typescript and uninstalling those packages required but i'm still getting this error.

Here's the error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-animator/angular/animator.module.js 8:145-163
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-animator/angular/animation.service.js 10:149-167
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-animator/angular/animates.directive.js 139:201-219
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-animator/angular/animator.module.js 16:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-animator/angular/animation.service.js 15:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-animator/angular/animates.directive.js 144:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-animator/angular/animates.directive.js 140:29-52
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareDirective' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-animator/angular/animator.module.js 8:26-47
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-animator/angular/animation.service.js 10:28-49
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-animator/angular/animates.directive.js 139:29-50
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-animator/angular/animation.service.js 11:29-53
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-animator/angular/animator.module.js 10:26-48
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjector' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-animator/angular/animator.module.js 9:26-48
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "next-v8.1.2-lite",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.8.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "css-animator": "^2.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-click-outside": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "screenfull": "^4.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.801.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.30",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: it seems css-animator library is not compatible with old angular. you either find a replacement for the library, or update angular to newer version or just drop the functionality that the library brings